# Ubuntu / PopOS 21.04 intel 2760 Bluetooth audio randomly disconnects

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, pop-os, bluez

I'm running into something which seems like a pretty exotic problem.

The config is:

- Lenovo T440p with Intel 2760 WiFi/Bluetooth
- Ubuntu 20.04 -> updated to PopOS 20.04 -> updated to PopOs 21.04
- Sennheiser Momentum True Wireless 2
- PulseAudio swapped for PipeWire
- BlueZ 5.56

I've had some complex issues where it was almost impossible to connect the headphones in SBC mode, only in HSP, and stuttering / degrading sound when initially using PulseAudio. I switched to PipeWire and was able to connect and play through A2DP, but the sound was very choppy and stuttered. This was to the point where the sound was basically garbled.
As posted on other threads, I've modified the bluetoothd config to contain `--noplugin=avrcp --experimental`. The latter I've added just to see if I can get the battery percentage reported.

After many reboots, seemingly randomly, the sound started working perfectly. A2DP  + aptX codec. Annoyingly, this is immediately after I installed Wireshark to try and see if it's a pattern I could potentially identify and search about.

It worked for about 2-3 minutes, then dropped, (sound started playing through the laptop's speakers) then reconnected and started playing through the earbuds again. This seems to happen every few minutes.

Investigating other threads, I've tried downgrading the firmware files to those of an earlier kernel version. I can't remember off the top of my head what the version was, but I can definitely have a look for it, if anyone thinks it would provide them valuable insight.

It might be worth mentioning that the headphones work perfectly fine when connected to two different macs and a Pixel 2 XL.

I have been trying to sort these issues out for quite some days now, and I seem to have reached a point where I can no longer find things I can try. The only thing that's left on my list is to upgrade BlueZ, but I feel this might not make a difference...

Update:
I have updated BlueZ to 5.62 and this made no difference.

Inspecting `dmesg`, it seems like the USB device (intel 2760) just decides to disconnect and reconnect afterwards.

I also used an ethernet connection and disabled WiFi to make sure it's not a matter of interference.

I booted from a live Ubuntu 20.04 USB stick, and the behaviour is identical (just that it uses SBC instead of A2DP).

Knowing it works on a 2015 13" MacBook Pro (in macOS), I tried booting Ubuntu 20.04 and 18.04 on it to see what would happen. 20.04 is not detecting the MBP's WiFi/BT card, but 18.04 is. In 18.04, I still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the most appropriate solution for everyone, but it's what proved to work for me.

I've redone the whole configuration from scratch, just to make sure nothing was broken in the process. I ended up swapping PulseAudio with PipeWire. For those interested in doing so, there are plenty of tutorials explaining exactly how this should be performed.

To no avail, neither PulseAudio nor PipeWire generate any improvements. Therefore, I decided that my last attempt would be to upgrade the T440p's WiFi/BT card. I chose Intel's AX210. Everything now works perfectly fine, both in terms of Bluetooth and WiFi.

The downside is that it's not a straightforward swap and you will need to flash your BIOS with a modified one so that the WiFi module allowlist is removed. More resources can be found online on this topic. An alternative to this overly-complicated process would probably be to buy a USB Bluetooth dongle.